# STL map to generic vector C++

Tags: c++, stl

I want to implement a map, which maps a string to a generic vector.

I want to do this:

```
std::map<std::string, std::vector<class T> > myMap;
```

Assuming the proposed myMap had the following inserted into it, it could be used as such:

```
vector<int> intVec = myMap["ListOfInts"]; // Works because "ListOfInts" maps to a vector<int>
vector<string> stringVec = myMap["ListOfStrings"]; // Works because "ListOfInts" maps to a vector<string>
```

When I declare the map with the above syntax the compiler has a heart attack.

Can anybody make any suggestions? Or a better associate array option in C++ (suggest non-boost before boost).

Comment: You would need your map value to be a variant type, there's no standard variant type so you would either have to implement your own or use something like [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/variant.html).

Comment: How many different `T` do you need for your std::vector<class T>? You could get away with a polymorphic container if you can figure out what to cast to via RTTI or via some kind of ID you implement yourself.

Comment: C++ is statically typed and map value-types must be all the same in a map. If you tell us the real problem you're trying to solve we may be able to indicate a C++-idiomatic way, or look at `boost::variant`.

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve?  By your description, it seems you are taking a very *Pythonic* approach, when in fact there may be a completely different pattern for the same problem in C++.

Comment: seems it requires std::map<std::string,(any type)> myMap;

Comment: If your compiler gets a heartattack, you should definitely get another one that produces readable error messages.

Comment: An XML file specifies parameters which we seek to pass to an application. The XML will specify an ID (or key) of a parameter list, as well as the type of the list as a node attribute. e.g. <params1 type="uint_32"><param>123</param></params1><params2 type="string"><param>"paramstring"<param></params2>. I want to build a map which can permit users to index on "params1" or "params2" and then be provided with a vector of the type specified. The user knows the type yes, but in the framework we want this expressed generically until the XML file is parsed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you know the type you want when you are writing your code, I propose this approach (untested):

```
// base class for any kind of map
class BaseMap {
 public:
  virtual ~BaseMap() {}
}; 

// actual map of vector<T>
template<typename T>
class MapT : public BaseMap, public std::map<std::string, std::vector<T>> {};

class MultiMap {
 public:
   template<typename T> 
   std::vector<T>& get(const std::string& key) {
     std::unique_ptr<BaseMap>& ptr = maps_[std::type_index(typeid(T))];
     if (!ptr) ptr.reset(new MapT<T>());
     return ptr->second[key];
   }
 private:
   std::map<std::type_index, std::unique_ptr<BaseMap>> maps_;
}

int main() {
  MultiMap map;
  std::vector<int>& intVec = map.get<int>("ListOfInts");
  std::vector<std::string>& stringVec = map.get<std::string>("ListOfStrings");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could work for you:

```
template <typename T>
class MyMap  {
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<typename T> > map;
public:
    /*...*/
};
```

Answer (score 0):

With C++11, you can use `using`, it does exactly what you want:

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>

template<typename T> using mymap = std::map<std::string, std::vector<T>>;

int main()
{
    mymap<int> intmap;
    mymap<std::string> stringmap;

    std::vector<int> intvec = intmap["test"];
    std::vector<std::string> stringvec = stringmap["test"];

    return 0;
}
```

<kbd>[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2a9f11be909b6643)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this isn't quite what I seek to do. I don't want to create more than one instance of the map, but within it store multiple vectors any type.

Comment: No problem ;-) After reading your question again, I think I should have found that out myself. I guess I was confused because it is not a typical C++ way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

As mattnewport said `boost::variant` is one option.

Or to support any types, use `boost::any` by explicit using `any_cast`.

Considering boost might be heavy weight, maybe you can reinvent the wheel and simplify it, so that is non boost any more? lol

Answer (score -2):

Template arguments must be decided compile time. If you want each key of your map to correspond to a vector of a different type, it won't really work. You can get around it with a polymorphic container that returns a void* that you cast to the correct type, but I would suggest trying to find another way to do whatever you want to do with your map first.

Comment: The polymorphic container should probably not contain return `void*`, since that doesn't provide a way to figure out what the type is. Better would be to require that the container itself is upcast (via a switch on typeid or a custom id) to the appropriate subclass and then the real type be returned.

Comment: If it returns a void*, it assumes that the caller knows what type it returns. Very unsafe. I suppose upcasting could be a lot safer.

Comment: is "ListOfInts" refers to vector<int> only?